# Dropdown with delete options inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I implement delete on click of a tag? When I delete click something, the view is not reflected until I do refresh.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
                <span ng-repeat="tag in tag track by $index" data-toggle="dropdown">[[tag]]</span>
                <!--<a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>-->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li ng-click="deleteHashtag(p_id, tag, $index)" class="cursor">Delete</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li ng-click="showHashtags(tag)" class="cursor">View All</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Below is the Angular code

```
  $scope.deleteHashtag = function(p_id,hashtag, index){

        $http.get("/api/hashtag/delete?contactId="+p_id.toString()+"&hashtag="+hashtag.toString())
            .success(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                if(response.SuccessCode){
                    console.log("Deleted Tag");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Delete fail");
                }
            });
        $scope.hashtag.splice(index, 1);
    };
```

Comment: Please add the function code too.

Comment: I added the angular code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `ng-repeat` attribute inside the dropdown div.  That way you will get a separate dropdown for each tag.  You may need to turn the dropdown `div` into a `span` for it to look the same.

I wrote a little demo page that seems to do what you want.  Click on each tag to bring up its own dropdown menu, then click delete and watch it go away.  The demo code is below, and also lives in plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lA2Qmx69k4heyYmVFt1m).

Some things to watch out for if you copy/paste:

1. The array of tags is called `tags` in my code.  It was referred to as `tag` in your html and `hashtag` in your javascript.
2. I used `$parent` to access the dummy `p_id` variable since it's now being accessed from within the `ng-repeat`.

Good Luck!

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.tags = ['javascript', 'webgl', 'angularjs', 'twitter-bootstrap', 'jquery'];
        $scope.p_id = 'some value';

        $scope.deleteHashtag = function(p_id, hashtag, index) {
            // I removed the api call here since I don't have access to it and
            // it doesn't seem to be part of the problem.  You may want to put
            // the splice inside the success method instead of outside though.
            console.log('delete hash tag ' + p_id + ' ' + hashtag + ' ' + index);
            $scope.tags.splice(index, 1);
        };

        $scope.showHashtags = function(tag) {
            console.log('show hash tags');
            // some function that does something not related to the problem at hand.
        };

      }]);
    </script>
    <style> 
      .spacey { margin-left: 3px; margin-right: 3px;} 
      .cursor { cursor: pointer; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
        <span class="dropdown cursor" ng-repeat="tag in tags track by $index">
          <span class="label label-default spacey" data-toggle="dropdown">{{tag}}</span>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ng-click="deleteHashtag($parent.p_id, tag, $index)" class="cursor">Delete</li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li ng-click="showHashtags(tag)" class="cursor">View All</li>
          </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `this.tag`

```
<li ng-click="deleteHashtag(p_id, this.tag, $index)" class="cursor">Delete</li>
```

In case its not working, please post ur angular code as well

Comment: @JimmyPaul: Hi,few suggestionz: 1>>  Plz dont entirely change ur question (in this case u have changed ur question after editing, making my answer completely irrelevant ), incase you do please add it as  **Update** , so that it helps others.

2>> I am not sure abt the `view` u r talking abt.May be some binding issue. I think u need to clarify it more with code or better provide us a plunker. It would save time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<li ng-click="deleteHashtag(p_id, tag, $index)" class="cursor">Delete</li>` element is outside `ng-repeat`, so you pass to the `deleteHashtag` function full tag list. `ng-repeat` repeats the element where it is inserted and every child element.

Comment: and how do I pass the deleteHashtag function the full tag list?

Comment: Firstly, you use the same name for your collection of tags and temp variable in ng-repeat. It's not good practice and I suggest you to change it, for example `ng-repeat="tagy in tag track by $index".
Secondly, if you want to pass a simple tag to your deleteHashtag function you must surround it with ng-repeat.

Comment: At this moment you repeat `span` element, but not `ul` element. So you have n `span`s and only one `ul` and every `span` opens the same `ul` dropdown-menu.